# Is it possible to control the GUI camera with python to follow a model?

Tags: python, gazebo-camera

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Using the current Gazebo GUI it is possible to focus the camera on any model using the "Move To" option. However, the camera doesn't "attach" to the model, i.e. the camera doesn't follow the model once it moves. Is there a way of calling "Move To" from python or calling some service that moves the camera so it will track the model automatically?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1649/is-it-possible-to-control-the-gui-camera-with-python-to-follow-a-model?/) by [EricSidorov](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/116/ericsidorov/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 53 on 2013-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is on my todo list. There is a function within `gazebo/rendering/UserCamera.hh` to follow a model (look for TrackVisual function). I need to properly expose this function to the GUI.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EricSidorov](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/116/ericsidorov/) on 2013-03-12**:
Great! It would be very useful to have such a feature

**Comment by [bugmenot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3784/bugmenot/) on 2017-09-04**:
Is there a way to set this from GUI by now?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-09-04**:
You can right-click a model and choose "Follow"